# how to group data into separate lists with distinct values c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable as below,

[image]

I have a service which returns list ,
[image]

i want to group data with distinct rowid and field name using linq and put them in
a separate lists. how can i achieve it?

here is my code for grouping by id

```
   var query = ae.Result.CommonDataValues.GroupBy(item => item.RowID)
                      .Select(g => g.Max(item => item.ID));
```

Comment: Where is your code? I see only table without any duplication of rowid and field name pairs. And then I see edited screenshot of something

Comment: `ToDictionary<int, List<OfWhat>>` comes to mind...

Comment: The extension ae.Result.CommonDataValues.ToLookup(...) sounds like a possible fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want/have a class which maps these properties like:

```
public class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RecordID { get; set; }
    public int RecordFieldData { get; set; }
    public int RowID { get; set; }
    public int FieldID { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
}
```

and you want a  `List<List<Data>>` which contains a `List<Data>` for every unique `RowID`+`FieldName` combination, you can `GroupBy` an anonymous type:

```
List<List<Data>> allData = data.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { RowID = r.Field<int>("RowID"), FieldName = r.Field<string>("FieldName") })
    .Select(g => g
        .Select(r => new Data
        {
            RowID = g.Key.RowID,
            FieldName = g.Key.FieldName,
            FieldID = r.Field<int>("RowID"),
            ID = r.Field<int>("ID"),
            RecordFieldData = r.Field<int>("RecordFieldData"),
            RecordID = r.Field<int>("RecordID")
        })
        .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

If you want to use a `Dictionary` instead with the `RowId` + `FieldName` as key:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, string>, List<Data>> allData = data.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { RowID = r.Field<int>("RowID"), FieldName = r.Field<string>("FieldName") })
    .ToDictionary(
        g => Tuple.Create(g.Key.RowID, g.Key.FieldName), 
        g => g.Select(r => new Data
            {
            RowID = g.Key.RowID,
            FieldName = g.Key.FieldName,
            FieldID = r.Field<int>("RowID"),
            ID = r.Field<int>("ID"),
            RecordFieldData = r.Field<int>("RecordFieldData"),
            RecordID = r.Field<int>("RecordID")
        })
        .ToList());

// lookup with RowId + FieldName, f.e.:
List<Data> datas;
if(allData.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create(1, "name"), out datas))
{
    // dictionary contains this data
}
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan: edited to show how to get a dictionary instead. [`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx) is an extension method which returns the field of a `DataRow`. I always use it because it's strongly typed and since it supports nullable types.

Comment: It groups the data, is there any way that i can generate a databale out of it in silverlight client?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the linq GroupBy, and then use the ForEach?

Something like the following;

```
            // Group the result by rowId
            finalData.GroupBy(x => x.rowid).ForEach(group =>
            {
                // Group would be the items which you are after...
                // Do your logic here?
            });
```

You can create the ForEach IEnumerable function, by adding this extension in your project;

```
public static void ForEach(this IEnumerable enumeration, Action action)
{
    foreach(T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

You would be able to get your MAX, etc, and all that you are after by accessing the group variable in the ForEach then... It should work for you.

Comment: Final data is not a list, its a dictionary. i want to filter from the ae.result.commondatavalues not from FinalData

Comment: @Sajeetharan you can use the .AsEnumerable(), to convert?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant

```
var query = from cdv in ae.Result.CommonDataValues
            group cdv by new {cdv.RowID, cdv.FieldName} into g
            select g.ToList()
```

if you want groupping only for one field yo can try this

```
var query = from cdv in ae.Result.CommonDataValues
            group cdv by new cdv.RowID into g
            select g.ToList()
```