# How to segregate data into different buckets using LINQ in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am new to VB.NET and can't find a way to segregate data into different buckets using LINQ in VB.NET ?

I have a list of objects and based on a particular property, I want to divide it based on distinct values for the property.

**Edit:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<DemoClass> ListDemoClass = new List<DemoClass>();

    DemoClass demo1 = new DemoClass();
    demo1.city = "Pune";
    demo1.name = "Pranav";
    ListDemoClass.Add(demo1);

    DemoClass demo2 = new DemoClass();
    demo1.city = "Pune";
    demo1.name = "Brij";
    ListDemoClass.Add(demo2);

    DemoClass demo3 = new DemoClass();
    demo1.city = "Pune";
    demo1.name = "Piyush";
    ListDemoClass.Add(demo3);

    DemoClass demo4 = new DemoClass();
    demo1.city = "NJ";
    demo1.name = "Igal";
    ListDemoClass.Add(demo4);

    DemoClass demo5 = new DemoClass();
    demo1.city = "NJ";
    demo1.name = "Mithun";
    ListDemoClass.Add(demo5);

    List<List<DemoClass>> buckets = ListDemoClass
        .GroupBy(x => x.city)
        .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
        .ToList();
}
```

Expected output is a list containing two lists of 2 and 3 objects respectively based on the city.

However this is not working. The result is I have a list of list of 1 and 4 items, which comes to be wrong. In the second list ,the objects are null.

Comment: What have you tried/researched? Because there is a LINQ method delivering exactly what you want.

Comment: Very unclear question. You don't have any code, sample data, expected result, etc...?

Comment: @TimSchmelter : I read your answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699138/how-to-group-data-into-separate-lists-with-distinct-values-c , but it is creating a new object inside . I want to use the same objects as in my case, it is very heavy.

Comment: The question is too vague. Add some examples!

Comment: @Harvey : Have updated the question with some test code.

Comment: @Pranav: change your democode so that you don't initialize only `demo1` properties.

Comment: I feel stupid beyond measure. Thanks a lot Tim for this. This was my first posting experience at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is pretty unclear but maybe this helps anyway, use `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

VB:

```
Dim buckets As List(Of List(Of ClassName)) = list.
        GroupBy(Function(x) x.PropertyName).
        Select(Function(grp) grp.ToList()).
        ToList()
```

C#

```
List<List<ClassName>> buckets = list
     .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyName)
     .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
     .ToList();
```

---

Your demo code only initializes `demo1` properties not the other objects.

Comment: I tested this and have updated the original post. Does not seem to be working.

Comment: @Pranav: there's a bug in your  demo code. You are always initializing `demo1` properties. Copy&paste issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
Dim result As List(Of List(Of SomeType)) = list.GrouBy(Function(x) x.Property).Select(Function(x) x.ToList()).ToList()
```

In C#, you would group the items to a list of lists in the following way:

```
List<List<SomeType>> result = list.GrouBy(x => x.Property).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: I need the List<List<sometype>> . The above groupby won't work.

Comment: I tested the above with some code, I pasted in the original post. Doesn't seem to be working.